# Safari Issue: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file

Tags: java, safari, applet, jnlp, japplet

Facing issue invoking java applet from my jsf page using JNLP file on Safari browser in Windows:
**java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1013478509 in class file**

I am able to invoke the same applet properly in **Firefox, Chrome and IE**.

This is how i am using the jnlp reference in my faces page:

```
<object classid="java:my.oddc.client.SimpleScanApplet.class" 
                    type="application/x-java-applet"
                    height="100%" width="100%" >
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="/wcc/wcc/upload/scan_client.jnlp"/>
    <param name="ServerURL"
          value="#{pageFlowScope.UploadBean.scanFileURL}"/>
</object>
```

Alternatively, i tried using embed and applet tags but didn't help.

Also, i have a mandate to pass few parameters to the applet after invoking.

The scan_client.jnlp file contains references to the required jars and nativelibs.

Help appreciated..on what to make it work on Safari (Windows)?

Comment: *"Help appreciated?"*  Is that a question?  If it is, it is one only you can answer.

Answer (score 0):

The magic value spells `<htm` so it is likely there is a 404 in there (resources are not where the object element suggests they are.

Comment: Facing this issue only on Safari. If it was a resource conflict it should have equally not run on any other browsers.